# How to implement validation using express-validator for the nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, express-validator

I created a model as follow:
[image: the model for buying, this used mongoose]

in the model "name", "commodityID", "totalAmount" are required, but notice commodity ID and totalAmount is part of an inner object "productDetails", and now I am using express-validator to do server-side validation as like this
[image: this is the api through which the application can interact]

this validation works for "name" fields which make sense but it doesn't work for the "totalAmount" and "commodityID" which are fields of an inner object,
and it is the pics I took throw postman
[image: this is a request and response made by postman]

may you guys show me the right way to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use Wildcard * for nested Objects [Read
>   Here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/wildcards.html)

```
   [
        check('name', " ").not().isEmpty()
        check('productDetails.commdityID', " ").not().isEmpty()
        check('productDetails.totalAmount', " ").not().isEmpty()
    ]
```

Answer (score 15):

**for array** i.e

```
productDetails: [
  {
    commodityID: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "commodity",
    },
    perOnePrice: { type: String, required: true },
    totalAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
    
  },
],
```

**use**

```
[
 body('productDetails.*.commodityID').not().isEmpty()
 body('productDetails.*.perOnePrice').not().isEmpty()
 body('productDetails.*.totalAmount').not().isEmpty()
]
```

**For nested object**, lets suppose:

```
productDetails: {
    commodityID: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "commodity",
    },
    perOnePrice: { type: String, required: true },
    totalAmount: { type: Number, required: true },      
  },
```

**use**

```
[
 body('productDetails.commodityID').not().isEmpty()
 body('productDetails.perOnePrice').not().isEmpty()
 body('productDetails.totalAmount').not().isEmpty()
]
```